# Looking for a free SMS gateway that works with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms

I have developed a Website in ASP.NET 2.0 I want to send an SMS to every person who  registers to my site. I want to do it in C# code, is there any service[webservice] which I can use and send free SMS to any mobile.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Giving away your users' phone numbers to somebody, who offers free sms services is probably not a good idea, if you don't know the provider. Likely their mobile phones end up spammed.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of almost every question in these categories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%20sms

Comment: Hai, I want my website to be abnormally obnoxious.  Can you help?

Comment: Hai, it is fun being ass on stackoverflow, can you show me how better to be ass, Will?

Comment: This is not duplicate, he is asking for the name of a free service as well as how to send it.

Comment: @Will Those comments are not called for, they help no one.

Comment: I don't agree that sending every registration an SMS message, but I would love to know of a service that would allow me to send SMS via C# for free.

Comment: Deviant: I just posted an answer below which may interest you then. They seem to have a pretty standard API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free SMS API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238579/free-sms-api)

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not endorsing your methods nor this service, I did stumble upon a writeup of Zeep Mobile by [ReadWriteWeb](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/zeep_mobile_free_sms_gateway.php). If you are comfortable with them inserting ads into the SMS, this may be for you.

Comment: *bookmarked, thanks. I promise to only send SMS msgs to the users I don't like. ;)

Comment: Deviant: It doesn't bother me one way or another. I think people are getting their panties in a twist over this way too much. We shouldn't judge another user over what he is planning to do with his website. I myself would never want to send SMS messages to anybody if I were making a site, and if I were a user, I would never give my number to receive those SMS messages. It's simple user choice.

Answer (score 2):

You should just allow them to enter one more more email address. If people want an SMS they can enter the email address from their providers gateway.  This would allow allow them to receive a message on a mobile/PDA style device without dealing with SMS.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, does it?

Comment: It is an answer.  And unless this guy doesn't want people to signup for his blog it's probably a good one.

Comment: No it doesn't Cerebrus. It's pretty common practice on StackOverflow for users to get self-righteous and tell the OP what they should think or do instead of answering straightforward (or simply not answering). For all we know this is a business rule laid down by the OP's client. Who are we to tell him how to design his project when he comes asking for a service referral.

Comment: hi Matthew whited, just to post you.. the site which i have developed is not (http://aledaata.blogspot.com) it is my blog,
the site which i have developed is different its a MLM site, so whenever a person joins the Network i want to send him an sms that he has joined to the XXX MLM network.. he is in (Left/Right) of Mr/Ms XXX.

Comment: Are you able to send email?  Most service providers (at least here in the US) support email gateways.  And example would be <NUMBER@txt.att.net> and it would allow the user to enter their SMS optionally.  You might note some of the common gateways in your area on the site for people to use.  On a different note I did check out your site.  Some of the photos are just amazing, kind of a shame I can't read your posts.  Good Luck.

Comment: @Matt, Unfortunately here in India we dont have that option yet :(
And Thank you for visiting my blog... keep checking.. u can get to see some awesome places in INDIA...

Jai Ho...