# OpenSource SMS Gateway - .Net (C# or VB.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sms

Is any opensource SMS (Short Message Service) gateway written in C# or VB.Net.

Gateway must support AT command mode.

I don't need SMS service, I need library to communicate with mobile phone or GSM modem (AT command mode)

Comment: Have a look at:<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793323/looking-for-a-free-sms-gateway-that-works-with-c<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392542/send-free-sms-from-c-asp-net<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=free+sms+gateway+c%23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting question...  The AT command set is for controlling a communications device (modem, phone, etc) attached to your computer.   A 'Gateway' is *usually* a service available through the internet that provides equivalent functionality so that you don't need to have an actual device attached to your computer.

If you want to use the AT command set to control a phone, there's a few things to note:

1. Many phones, especially the newer ones, don't support an AT command set.  I know that the old Nokia 5120 does.
2. Sometimes you have to install the phone's 'PC Suite' software before you can access the phone's AT command set
3. For some newer phones you can only access the AT command set if you connect to the phone via Bluetooth.

If you have a phone that suppors it:

1. Plug it in  (or establish a Serial Bluetooth connection to the phone)
2. Use Hyperterminal to connect to the phone.
3. Start typing and see if the phone responds.

You may have to install the PC Suite software.  On the other hand, installing the PC Suite software may interfere with getting to the phone's AT command set...

The best wat is to give it a go!